# "ofstream" as function argument

Tags: c++, function, ofstream

Is there a way to pass output stream as argument like

`void foo (std::ofstream dumFile) {}`

I tried that but it gave

`error : class "std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>" has no suitable copy constructor`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Of course there is. Just use reference.
Like that:

```
void foo (std::ofstream& dumFile) {}
```

Otherwise the copy constructor will be invoked, but there is no such defined for the class `ofstream`.

Comment: Just a note: once constructed it typically doesn't matter what kind of stream you got and it tends to be preferable to use `std::ostream&` (note the absense of `f`).

Comment: Or even more generic: `template<typename Char, typename Traits> … std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>&`

Comment: If I do `void foo (const std::ofstream& dumFile)` what does it do, does it write to `dumFile` and cannot change it's address, or it cannot write into it?

Answer (score 14):

You have to pass a reference to the `ostream` object as it has no copy constructor:

```
void foo (std::ostream& dumFile) {}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a C++11 conformant compiler and standard library, it should be ok to use

```
void foo(std::ofstream dumFile) {}
```

as long as it is called with an rvalue. (Such calls will look like `foo(std::ofstream("dummy.txt"))`, or `foo(std::move(someFileStream))`).

Otherwise, change the parameter to be passed by reference, and avoid the need to copy/move the argument:

```
void foo(std::ofstream& dumFile) {}
```

Comment: Given that `std::ofstream` has a move constructor, it works to pass a temporary object to a function declared as `void foo(std::ofstream)` using e.g. `foo(std::ofstream("file"))`. Note that gcc's standard library hasn't implemented this constructor, yet, while clang's standard library has (i.e. the above code compiles with clang but not with gcc; gcc is wrong).