# Basic use of ofstream by another function

Tags: c++, ofstream

My program is very easy, all the mess happens around the passing of the ofstream pointer as shown below.

Main programm:

```
int main()
{...
ofstream otf;
otf.open("hex_movie.xyz");
....
write(int (1),oc,nx,ny,otf,ck)
}
```

And in the write.h, it begins with

```
int write(int TYPE,int *oc,int nx,int ny,ofstream otf, double ck)
{.... return 0;}
```

I used Xcode to debug it, and it shows (only on the line of the write fucntion, sorry I cannot upload a screen shot)

**Xcode/GGK/GGK/ggk.cpp:110:28: Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream')**

Can anybody help me with this, thank you very much! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["ofstream" as function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658720/ofstream-as-function-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the signature of the function

```
int write(int TYPE,int *oc,int nx,int ny,ofstream otf, double ck)
```

the argument `otf` is of type `ofstream`, which means call by value; consequently, `otf` will be a copy of the agrument of the caller. You could change the signature to

```
int write(int TYPE,int *oc,int nx,int ny,ofstream& otf, double ck)
```

which will use call by reference and will use the same object as the caller.

Comment: Got it! I'm just a beginner, thank you very much!
: )
 I'll tick the answer later, for it has been solved so quick! LOL

Answer (score 2):

You are currently passing by value `otf` try passing it by reference

```
int write(int TYPE,int *oc,int nx,int ny,ofstream& otf, double ck)
```

Comment: I dont know whether it is a typo, but its ofstream&, as addressed by the 1st comment.
Thank you anyway